# Strange behaviour of div load jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using Jquery/Ajax/Spring MVC in my application. I am trying to do simple login but getting stuck at the div load in jquery in Functions.js. The code does not print Authenticated even when it is. Only when i refresh the page i see it written authenticated. 
I have tried on Chrome, IE and FF but same effect. Pl. suggest what am i missing here.Thanks

**login JSP -**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success spacer" onclick="loginToAccount('login.html', 'loginForm');"> Sign in
     </button                       
  </div>
</div>
```

**template jsp**

```
<div id="refreshDiv">
    <sec:authorize access="isAnonymous()">
            anonymous
    </sec:authorize>

    <sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
            authenticated
            <li><a href="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_logout" />">Log out</a></li>
    </sec:authorize>

</div>
```

**Functions.js**

```
function loginToAccount(targetUrl,form){

  postAjaxData(null,'content',targetUrl, form ,null, null);
  welcomeUser();
}

function welcomeUser(){
  $('#refreshDiv').load(' #refreshDiv').html();
  return false;

}
```

Comment: why `$('#refreshDiv').load(' #refreshDiv').html();` and not `$('#refreshDiv').html( "<some_text_you_want_to_add>" );`?

Comment: You are refereshing the div before the post has completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are refreshing the `refreshDiv` before the login ajax request has completed. You need a callback.

```
function postAjaxData(stuff) {
  // of course, you'll have to fill
  // this in with your ajax method 
  // of choice, just make sure you  
  // return a promise object.
  return $.ajax(stuff);
}

function loginToAccount(targetUrl,form){
  postAjaxData(null,'content',targetUrl, form ,null, null).done(function () {
    welcomeUser();
  }); 
}

function welcomeUser(){
  $('#refreshDiv').load(' #refreshDiv').html();
  return false;
}
```

Additionally, when you .load a specific div, you're loading that div, not it's contents, so you'll want to go one element up.

```
$("#parentOfrefreshDiv").load(" #refreshDiv")
```

or give refreshDiv a child to target:

```
$("#parentOfrefreshDiv").load(" #refreshDiv > div");
```

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out the bug. After trying for few hours I had introduced error by which i was calling refreshDiv before login ajax request has completed, as you mentioned. So, that part I changed to what I previously had after reading your comment. My main mistake was in the way I was calling load function. I now have      it as $('#refreshDiv').load(' #refreshDiv', function(){$(this).children().unwrap()}); since loading refreshDiv itself will add one more child refreshDiv and that can be eliminated by unwrapping.

Comment: So, instead of $('#refreshDiv').load(' #refreshDiv').html(); am using $('#refreshDiv').load(' #refreshDiv') with the unwrap function.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want the following line to do, **but it is not valid jQuery**:

```
$('#refreshDiv').load(' #refreshDiv').html();
```

Maybe you wanted to write:

```
$('body').load(' #refreshDiv');
```

Which will replace existing content with the appropriate section in `template.jsp`.

Comment: hmm.... i would have to test this first to see if it works. `.load(' #refreshDiv` would be equivalent to `.load('./ #refreshDiv`, if jQuery allows it (which is the part i'm not sure about).

Comment: Still not valid jQuery though. Do you mean `.load('template.jsp #refreshDiv')`? This would be valid jQuery.

Comment: No, what i'm saying is The idea behind `.load(' #refreshDiv')` is that the target page is the current page, similar to `<a href=""></a>` or `.load('')`

Comment: And, `.load(' #refredhDiv')` should work. (though it may not do exactly what he wants) http://plnkr.co/edit/IMsAfox67HzMGEZRrtmb?p=preview

Comment: @KevinB I see what you mean now ... makes sense. I have updated my answer.